# why not using method call instead of using properties?

Tags: swift

I'm studying Swift language, and in github.com, i found [SwiftHelper](https://github.com/chalkers/SwiftHelpers).
In it's `IntHelper.swift` file, I found below code:

```
extension Int {  
    var isEven: Bool {  
        let remainder = self % 2  
        return remainder == 0  
    }  

    var isOdd: Bool {  
        return !isEven  
    }
}
```

why `isEven` and `isOdd` were written as properties, not method calls?

In this situation, Using property has any advantage over using method calls?

Answer (score 2):

In purely technical terms, there are no advantages or disadvantages to using a property over a method or vice versa<sup>*</sup> : the only difference is in readability.

In this particular case, I think that using an extension property makes for better readability than using a method call, because it reads better. Compare

```
if myInt.isOdd {
    ... // Do something
}
```

vs.

```
if myInt.isOdd() {
    ... // Do something
}
```

vs.

```
if isOdd(myInt) {
    ... // Do something
}
```

The first (property) and second (method) code fragments keeps words in the same order as they are in English, contributing to somewhat better readability. However, the second one adds an unnecessary pair of parentheses. For completeness, the third way of accomplishing the same task (a function) is less readable than the other two.

<sup>*</sup>  This also applies to other languages that support properties, for example, Objective-C and C#.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick answer! And the examples are also clear and easy to understand.

Comment: If `isOdd` is implemented as an extension method of `Int` then the method call would be `myInt.isOdd()`, not `isOdd(myInt)`.

Comment: @MartinR You're right, OP probably meant `myInt.isOdd()`. I mentioned that as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The properties used in the **extension** are what's known as **'computed properties'** - which in a lot of ways *are* like a method  :)  in that they don't store any state themselves, but rather return some computed value.

The choice between implementing a 'property' vs. a 'method' for something like this can be thought of in semantic terms; here, although the value is being computed, it simply serves to represent some information about the state of the object (*technically 'struct' in the case of Int*) in the way that you would expect a property to, and asking for that state isn't asking it to modify either itself or any of its dependencies.

In terms of readability, methods in Swift (even those without arguments) still require parens - you can see the difference that makes in this example:

```
// as a property
if 4.isEven { println("all is right in the world") }

// as a method
if 5.isEven() { println("we have a problem") }
```